# Application crashes when wxFileDialog is resized

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I maintain an application written using visual studio 2010 and wxWidgets version 2.8.10.  It has been reported to me that, under windows vista, the application will crash when displaying a wxFileDialog that is viewing a network drive and being resized.  The dialogue is invoked with the following code:

```
     wxFileDialog file_chooser(
        this,
        make_wxString(my_strings[strid_file_choose_caption]),
        make_wxString(frame->get_config()->get_last_os_dir()),
        wxT(""),            // default file
        make_wxString(loader->get_file_extension()),
        wxOPEN);
     int rcd = file_chooser.ShowModal();
```

Has anybody seen anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crashes inside the standard file dialog are almost invariably due to the presence of some buggy shell extension on the system. To say anything more you'd need to get the minidump (or at least a stack trace) at the moment of crash and debug it.